# mongodb slowness with large number of updates

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am using python(3.4) to parse a huge text file (~200MB, 500k lines) and add entries to mongodb (3.4.4). My program is something like this:

```
for line in file:
    if ‘some_string1’ in line:
        list1 = line.split(“,”)
        mydict[field1] = list1[0]
        mydict[field2] = list1[4]
        db.coll1.insert(mydict)

    elif ‘some_string2’ in line:
        list1 = line.split(“,”)
        mydict[field1] = list1[0]
        mydict[field2] = list1[4]
        mydict[notes] = “some_notes”
        db.coll1.update({“filed1”: mydict[“filed1”}, {"$set":{"notes": mydict["notes"]}}, upsert=False)
```

This program runs extremely slow ( 4-5 hours to process all the lines). I have tried setting filed1 as index but that did not help. Inserting into db is much faster but update is taking a lot of time. Is there any thing I can do to optimize the performance?

Comment: Learn about [bulk_write()](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.bulk_write)

Comment: @NeilLunn, Thanks for the suggestion. I tried bulk write and the performance was improved by ~8%. However, it still is a long time for me. Is there any other suggestion for performance improvement?

Comment: Then you are doing it wrong. Don't say *"I tried that"* when you don't include what you actually did in your question. If you are using correctly and you actually read the manual and the many answers with usage on this very site, then you would understand the correct usage, and the small improvement you mention suggests you do not. Simply replacing your `.update()` and `.insert()` methods above with `.bulk_write()` will do next to nothing, That is why I say **Learn** about `bulk_write()`

Comment: Since bulk_Write did not help much, I converted my file to a pandas dataframe. mongodb update statements were replaced by pandas dataframe merge. And, it is lightening fast. The whole program execution came down to minutes from hours.